# Infinitesimal Generator of A One Parameter Group

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

This is a small problem which drives me crazy.

Let $\varphi(x,y,t)=(F_1(x,y,t),F_2(x,y,t))$ be a one paramter transformation group on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $F_3(x,y,z,t)=\frac{D_1F_2+zD_2F_2}{D_1F_1+D_2F_1}$, then $\varphi^1(x,y,z,t)=(F_1, F_2, F_3)$ is also a one parameter group.

If the infinitesimal generator of $\varphi$ is $\xi\frac{\partial}{\partial x }+\eta\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, prove that the infinitesimal generator of $\varphi^1$ is

$\xi\frac{\partial}{\partial x }+\eta\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+[\eta_x+z(\eta_y-\xi_x)-z^2\xi_y]\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$

I just can't get the right form. I hope someone can show me the proof with specific procedures.

Answer (score 0):

This question is from Castillos. Unfortunately this the asker made a careless typo, hence the lack of answers.

The correct function is $$F_3(x,y,z,t) = \frac{D_1F_2 + zD_2F_2}{D_1F_1 + zD_2F_1}.$$

Next being a one-parameter group of transformations, we obtain the immediate identities $F_1(x,y,0) = x, F_2(x,y,0) = y$

Now recall the meaning of the abstract symbols $\xi = \frac{d}{dt} \Bigr\rvert_{t=0} F_1$ and $\eta = \frac{d}{dt} \Bigr\rvert_{t=0} F_2$. Therefore,

$$\frac{d}{dt} \Bigr\rvert_{t=0} F_3 = \frac{(\eta_x + z\eta_y)(1+0) - (z\xi_x + z^2\xi_y) }{(1 + 0)^2} = \eta_x +z(\eta_y - \xi_x) - z^2 \xi_y$$

as desired.